# Can prepositions be directly followed by that-clauses?

Tags: prepositions, clauses

As we know, many transitive verbs can be followed by that-clauses which serve as direct objects.
I was told by our linguists that some prepositions such as "except, but, in" could be directly followed by that-clauses. I doubted about it, but I could not find relevant examples, nor a specific answer on this site. I also checked from other sources and found no answers.

Comment: Sometimes, like if you say, "But that he convinces me he didn't do it, I won't take his case." "But" is being used in its prepositional sense of "with the exception of," the "that" clause serving as a noun clause that is the object of the preposition. Another example would be, "Let's do it now in that you will be busy later."

Comment: This is convincing.